# Declaring an NSDictionary with an NSString as its name

Tags: nsstring, nsdictionary, declaration

Ok, so I would like to create an NSDictionary, but the pointer should be followed by the value of an NSString that has been put in by the user. Is this possible? I imagine it would be something along the lines of this...

```
someNSString = _someTextField.text;
NSDictionary * {someNSString} = [NSDictionary dictionaryWithObjectsAndKeys:
[NSNumber numberWithInt:someUnimportantVariable], @"someUnimportantKey",...nil]
```

Thanks in advance, I realize that this is either completely not possible or there is a pretty simple solution. Either way, I'm sorry if I wasted your time.

Comment: After testing this, it didnt work for me.

Comment: I'm really just trying to see what the syntax is for the curly braces portion of my code. The rest is just further description.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you could try creating a "dictionary of dictionaries". something to the effect of:

```
someNSString = _someTextField.text;
NSDictionary *myDictionary = [[NSDictionary alloc] init];
[myDictionary setObject:[NSDictionary dictionaryWithObjectsAndKeys: [NSNumber numberWithInt:someUnimportantVariable], @"someUnimportantKey",...nil] forKey:someNSString];
```

and if you wanted to get back that dictionary

```
NSDictionary someNSStringDictionary = [myDictionary objectForKey:someNSString];
```

let me know if it helps in any way.